# Confused on setting up a has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have been playing with setting up different relationships for a few hours now and I am not sure how to do a has_many relationship with what I am using. Not sure if it is just naming conflicts or my just not understanding.

Here is my database tables:

```
show_names (table name):
id
show_id
name

shows (table name):
id
length
synopsis
number_of_episodes
status
```

So each show has many possible names. So I want to setup a has_many relationship so I can call something like:

```
Show.all.shownames[0].name
```

That would give me the first name.

Here are my code samples for my models, and its where I think I am messing up.

```
class ShowName < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shows
end
```

and

```
class Show < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :shownames
end
```

Using ShowName.all works to get data and Show.all works too.

So I have 2 main questions about this.

1) Am I just misnaming something or putting it in the wrong place?
2) How do I access the show names? I know in other using has_one i just use the name of the entity does it work the same with has_many

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why do you need to separate the show names from the show? i mean, each of the shows has names right? or is this to catch multi-season shows?

Comment: Note that Show.all.shownames[0].name doesn't make sense in your setup. Show.all returns an array in which shownames will not be a method on.

Comment: @corroded each show will have 1 or more names. Not just what it is officially called, but what pop culture names it too.

Comment: @Austin That was me typing a bit fast I mean to type Show.all[0].show_names[0] something along those lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You flipped the belongs_to and has_many and needed an extra underscore.  Try this:

```
class ShowName < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :show
end
```

and

```
class Show < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :show_names
end
```

and now...

```
show = Show.first
show.show_names  =>  ["First name for first show", "Second name for second show"]
```